# MatPlotLib FuncAnimation doesnt work with non-zero interval or blit=True

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Just wanted to preface this with a huge thank you to the whole community, it's thanks to you that I've learned most of the what I know!

Anyway, I'm having an issue with MatPlotLib's animation module.

I've cut my code down to what seems to be the problem. The code below works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

ionFig = plt.figure(figsize=(18.0, 12.5))
ionPlot = ionFig.add_subplot(111)
ionScatter = []
plots = {}
plots['pos'] = [ [[0,2,4, 0,2,4],[1,1,1, 1,1,1]] , [[5,6,8, 5,6,8],[1,4,3, 1,4,3]] ]
ionPlot.set_xlim(0,10)
ionPlot.set_ylim(0,10)

for particle in range(len(plots['pos'])):
    ionScatter.append(ionPlot.scatter(plots['pos'][particle][0][0], plots['pos'][particle][1][0], s=6))

for scatter in ionScatter:
    scatter.remove()

def animate(i, ionScatter, plots):
    print i
    for particle in range(len(plots['pos'])):
        ionScatter[particle].set_offsets([plots['pos'][particle][0][i], plots['pos'][particle][1][i]])
    return ionScatter


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(ionFig, animate, fargs=[ionScatter, plots], frames=len(plots['pos'][0][0]), interval=0, blit=True, repeat=True)
ionFig.show()
```

but I'd like to set interval to a non-zero number, to slow down the animation. 
However, when I change the second last line to:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(ionFig, animate, fargs=[ionScatter, plots], frames=len(plots['pos'][0][0]), interval=100, blit=True, repeat=True)
```

The figure shows for a split second, and then closes.

Setting it to

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(ionFig, animate, fargs=[ionScatter, plots], frames=len(plots['pos'][0][0]), interval=100, blit=True, repeat=True)
```

causes the same error, and

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(ionFig, animate, fargs=[ionScatter, plots], frames=len(plots['pos'][0][0]), interval=0, blit=False, repeat=True)
```

Causes a blank window to appear and not disappear.

In all these cases I've got the callback printing out the iteration number i. In the first two cases it does so twice, but both are 0's.
In the last case, it does cycle through, but as I said the window is empty. That case is less interesting anyway as the interval is back to 0.

So for some reason, having a non-zero interval messes up my animation, any ideas why that could be? I've had a look around but couldn't seem to find much.

Don't imagine it makes much of a difference but I'm on Ubuntu 14.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a solution, although I don't know why it works.

It seems that using plt.show() as opposed to ionFig.show() allows an interval to be used. I'm assuming that using ionFig.show() isn't enough as it doesn't tell the animation to start itself, so another line may be needed if this is what one wants to do? Not really sure, if anyone knows anymore let me know.